# MySQL Group Per OrderBy

Tags: mysql

I have a data like this. I want to sort this data with a different ProviderId for each row.

```
Table1
ProviderId   Tags
1            home
2            phone
3            notebook
3            phone
2            ...
2            ...
1            ...
1            ...
```

Below I am attaching an example of what I want to do.

```
Table1
ProviderId   Tags
1            ...
2            ...
3            ...
1            ...
2            ...
3            ...
```

Comment: Future, dont post images when you can put text directly (format via curly brackets).  Also, please edit your existing post to indicate how/why basis of provider tags being 1 per provider before next tag.  What if one provider does not have all the given tags.  What happens.  Are you looking for what each provider has with respect to tags, or just the first one that they have.  Again, please EDIT your post and add more details.

Comment: The label doesn't matter. I just want to sort by provider id as in the example.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you have to use **Group by** for both columns and then **Order by** **ProviderId** just like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP by ProviderId, tags ORDER by ProviderId;
```

[image: Local Result]

Comment: @netdeveloper can you write in English, please?

Comment: This way I can't get the output I gave in the example.

Comment: @netdeveloper update your question and provide the data set you want to work with, and the output you want to get. do you have example **1 = phone, 2 = phone, 3 = phone, 1 = home, 2 = home, 3 = home, 1 = notebook, 2 = notebook, 3 = notebook** !!?